# Birthday reminder - Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, sync, facebook

I run Windows 7. I would like to know if there is any option to have a birthday reminder option or software for my PC. I would like to get dates from my Facebook contacts as well, so that it will be fine if there is any sync option.

Answer (score 1):

this is not the one I use. but it should work for you.

http://birthday-gadget.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/faq.html

Comment: which one do you use?

Comment: i think this one is online. i need some software to run in my pc.